# Compensating water pressure loss by gradually decreasing diameter of water pipes?

Tags: pressure, water

I have a real life situation to solve and I kindly ask for help.

My family lives in a dry area and we finally got permission to connect to water pipeline (far away). The disappointing side is that at the point of entry on our property the water pressure is quite low -- 2 bars (29 PSI) only, and we have to deliver it up the hill which is 25 meters (82 ft) tall.
This means the pressure of the water is too low to reach the top.

[image]

In such situations, using the water pump is a common solution.

But as the water pressure increases with lowering the diameter of the pipe, I wonder if we could compensate this **by gradually decreasing the water pipe diameter as we lay them up the hill** -- from 2 inches (inner) diameter (at the entry) down to 0.5 inches (at the top)? And avoid using the pump...

But the calculations are beyond me.

Comment: Unfortunately, you need a "booster" pump on the low end of your piping system, and there's no way to avoid that fact.

Answer (score 2):

The water pressure is enough for maybe 20m, but not 25.

There is no direct way to use your limited water pressure to achieve the full
height of your hill, but there IS a way to waste some water flow to
propel a small portion of the water to the hilltop.   It is a scheme called
a [hydraulic ram](https://www.nrcs.usda.gov/Internet/FSE_DOCUMENTS/nrcs142p2_041913.pdf).   The principle is that a flow of water is
allowed (at the low-altitude stream), and when it builds up momentum
the flow is blocked, and the transient pressure at the
blockage moves a small amount of water at a higher pressure.

It's noisy.   It rejects a large amount of water as waste, in order
to move a small amount uphill.  But, it works.  If the pipe is
filled from a flowing stream, a hydraulic ram at the fill point can
give you higher pressure (and the 'waste' water will flow harmlessly
downstream).   This is not ideal for a dry region.

At 2 bar, the water won't rise 25m, unless you apply suction (with an
old-fashioned hand pump, for instance) at the hilltop.  [Hand pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand_pump) 
The last 5m of rise just barely works with that scheme.